# merging and filling the NA values of another column based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dfs, a subset of which looks like this. Where available, I want the "NA" values to be replaced by the rsid values in the other df.

```
df1:
SNP          A1  A2   rsid
1:100000012   A   G   rs1234
1:1000066     T   C   <NA>
1:2032101     C   T   rs5678
```

```
df2:
SNP           A1  A2   rsid
2:107877      A   G   rs1112023
3:1000066     T   C   rs8213723
1:1000066     T   C   rs7778899
```

This is what I want where the NA is replaced by the rsid values of the other df. In this example, the rsid of row 3 for df2 replaces the NA value of the rsid for row 2 for df1. I only want the new df to include rows in df1, like so.

```
df3
SNP          A1  A2   rsid
1:100000012   A   G   rs1234
1:1000066     T   C   rs7778899
1:2032101     C   T   rs5678
```

I tried this, but am getting some error messages. Can someone help?

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
   group_by(SNP, A1, A2) %>%
   summarise(rsid = rsid[complete.cases(rsid)], .groups = 'drop')
```

```
Error: Column `rsid` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
```

Comment: Can you please update your post with the `dput` of the small data example that show the error.  As I mentioned below in the comments, one of the warning is based on the `factor` column level issue.  But, the error seems to be related to the package version of dplyr.  Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')` As of version `>= 1.0`, summarise can return length greater than 1

Comment: The version I have downloaded is 0.8.5. When I try the code you provided, I get the following error message, "Error: Column `RSID` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2."

Comment: Can you please check my update. thanks

Comment: yes, R just crashed for me so I will do so in a few minutes.

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade R and dplyr to the current versions because using older versions can get you into lot of troubles as behavior of functions have changed a bit

Comment: @akrun, I think I got it to work by uploading my version of dplyr and by reducing the number of columns to whatever was necessary for the merge. I do have 1 additional question. Is there a way to modify the code above so that the merge only includes rows from df1? I have modified my post to reflect this. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: I updated the post.  Please check thanks

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much, @akrun!! I am grateful for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind the datasets together with `bind_rows` and then do a group by summarise while removing the `NA` with `complete.cases` (`dplyr` version `>= 1.0`)

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
   group_by(SNP, A1, A2) %>%
   summarise(rsid = rsid[complete.cases(rsid)], .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  SNP         A1    A2    rsid     
#  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>    
#1 1:100000012 A     G     rs1234   
#2 1:1000066   T     C     rs7778899
#3 1:2032101   C     T     rs5678   
#4 2:107877    A     G     rs1112023
#5 3:1000066   T     C     rs8213723
```

---

If the version of `dplyr` is `< 1.0`, `summarise` expects the output to be of `length` 1  per group.  We can wrap it in a `list` and then `unnest`

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
   group_by(SNP, A1, A2) %>%
   summarise(rsid = list(rsid[complete.cases(rsid)])) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   unnest(c(rsid))
```

#### Update

Based on the updated post, if we need to update the column 'rsid' based on the second data, an option is to do a join and then assign (`:=`) after coalescing the 'rsid' columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, rsid := fcoalesce(rsid, i.rsid), on = .(SNP, A1, A2)]
```

-output

```
df1
#           SNP A1 A2      rsid
#1: 1:100000012  A  G    rs1234
#2:   1:1000066  T  C rs7778899
#3:   1:2032101  C  T    rs5678
```

---

A similar option is also possible with `dplyr`

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('SNP', 'A1', 'A2')) %>%       
  transmute(SNP, A1, A2, rsid = coalesce(rsid.x, rsid))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SNP = c("1:100000012", "1:1000066", "1:2032101"
), A1 = c("A", "T", "C"), A2 = c("G", "C", "T"), rsid = c("rs1234", 
NA, "rs5678")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(SNP = c("2:107877", "3:1000066", "1:1000066"), 
    A1 = c("A", "T", "T"), A2 = c("G", "C", "C"), rsid = c("rs1112023", 
    "rs8213723", "rs7778899")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I tried your code and I am getting some error messages. I edited my comment and inserted them above. Any thoughts on how to resolve these messages?

Comment: @D.Fowler Looks like you have `factor` columns.  It can be converted to `character` class. i.e. `df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE); df2 <- type.convert(df2, as.is = TRUE)` and then try